# How to create fake sound card on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, alsa

I want to run 'blender --background --python script.py' on my Ubuntu Server which does not physically have any sound equipment.

It turns out that blender requires sound card. I see following error message when I try to start it:

```
AL lib: pulseaudio.c:612: Context did not connect: Access denied
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: alsa.c:512: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
AL lib: oss.c:169: Could not open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory

Blender quit
```

Also when I run 'sudo modprobe snd-dummy' it says:

```
FATAL: Module snd_dummy not found.
```

I am completely unaware of how sound works in Linux and how Alsa works. Other SO questions point to outdated links and I could not work out what I should do. Please suggest me the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run blender without sound card just start it like:

```
blender -noaudio ...
```

Solved the issue for me.